# Is there an unknown iPhone trying to access my computer wirelessly?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, iphone, wireless-access-point, security-warning

My Mac asked me "Do you want to allow this computer to access information on "maria's iPhone"? I don't a maria -- is there any explanation for this? Could this pop up if someone tries to access it wirelessly?

Makes me feel a little creeped out. As far as I know, no one has been in my apartment that could have plugged their phone into my computer in the back room, but I don't know another way this could have popped up.

Comment: No; This only happens with a physical connection to the phone.

Comment: You text says that the Mac wants to access the phone, your title says the reverse. What is it? [Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing @JanDoggen I just edited it so hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: Your title still asks the reverse of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Someone is trying to connect BT by pairing, which can be ignored and requires a one time key from phone user to you to enable.  just noise. ignore it or turn off BLutooth. Then locate Maria and ask her out for coffee. :)

Comment: When I get on my phone, I can't see my computer in Bluetooth (though I did check and Bluetooth is "On" in system preferences in my Mac). How would someone try to connect to my computer with bluetooth if it doesn't show up in Bluetooth devices--how is my computer visible to her and not me?